# Debugging tools of an add-in in Excel for Windows

Tags: ms-office, office-js, microsoft-edge

I just updated my Excel to the following version (I use 32-bit rather than 64-bit Excel, though the Windows 10 is 64-bit).

[image]
[image]

And I just upgraded my Edge to the new Version 83.0.478.45 (Official build) (64-bit).

I have an Excel add-in (in local development) which does not work well in Excel for Windows. I want to debug it in Excel for Windows. However, my F12 tool cannot find the target to debug (though it still can find a target in IE + Excel Online).

So my questions are:

1. How to debug an office add-in in Excel for Windows of my version?
2. Which browser is my add-in in Excel for Windows using?

PS: a screenshot of Microsoft Edge DevTools:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) How to debug an office add-in in Excel for Windows of my version?**

**Debug using Microsoft Edge DevTools**

When the add-in is running in Microsoft Edge, you can use the Microsoft Edge DevTools.

1. Run the add-in.
2. Run the Microsoft Edge DevTools.
3. In the tools, open the Local tab. Your add-in will be listed by its
   name.
4. Click the add-in name to open it in the tools.
5. Open the Debugger tab.
6. Choose the folder icon above the script (left) pane. From the list
   of available files shown in the dropdown list, select the JavaScript
   file that you want to debug.
7. To set a breakpoint, select the line. You will see a red dot to the
   left of the line and a corresponding line in the Call stack (bottom
   right) pane.
8. Execute functions in the add-in as needed to trigger the breakpoint.

To get more detailed information and to know about how to debug using IE dev tools, you can refer to the link below.

[Debug add-ins using developer tools on Windows 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-using-f12-developer-tools-on-windows-10)

**2) Which browser is my add-in in Excel for Windows using?**

The following table shows which browser is used for the various platforms and operating systems.

[image]

Reference:

[Browsers used by Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins)

**Note:** **MS Edge legacy (EdgeHTML)** browser is used in the steps mentioned in the docs.

Comment: Sorry for being reactive lately. "In the tools, open the Local tab" ==> Where is the `Local tab` of Microsoft Edge DevTools?

Comment: In the docs, they are talking about Microsoft Edge DevTools Preview which you can download from this link. https://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/p/microsoft-edge-devtools-preview/9mzbfrmz0mnj?rtc=1&activetab=pivot:overviewtab If you launch the app, 2 tabs will appear. (1) Local (2) Remote See here: https://imgur.com/a/2KMwp0z